# Why does the following IF condition in ksh always evaluate to true?

Tags: unix, if-statement, ksh

Consider, below code works as expected:

```
if [[ $SOME_VARIABLE = "TRUE" ]]; then
   echo "Only echoed when \$SOME_VARIABLE stores string \"TRUE\"."
fi
```

But when I remove the space surrounding the equality operator it always evaluates to 0 exit status (At least that's what I assume it must be returning as it is taken as true):

```
if [[ $SOME_VARIABLE="TRUE" ]]; then
   echo "Always true."
fi
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Just to confirm whether the issue lies with the equality operator or not:

```
#!usr/bin/ksh

SOME_VARIABLE=FALSE

if [[ $SOME_VARIABLE == "TRUE" ]]; then
   echo "Only echoed when \$SOME_VARIABLE stores string \"TRUE\"."
fi


if [[ $SOME_VARIABLE=="TRUE" ]]; then
   echo "Always true."
fi


[kent@TEST]$ sh test.sh
Always true.
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Summary:

1. Using `=` is the same as `==` above, but is obsolete.
2. ALWAYS mind your spaces.

Comment: = is an assignment operator while == and === are comparison operators.

Comment: Well my observations are different. When I user '=' surrounded by spaces it correctly acts as a comparison operator. [See here for more examples](http://www.well.ox.ac.uk/~johnb/comp/unix/ksh.html#branching).

Comment: .. [String comparisons in Korn](http://www.well.ox.ac.uk/~johnb/comp/unix/ksh.html#comparisons).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `ksh(1)`:

> Conditional Expressions.
>
> ```
>    A conditional expression is used with the [[ compound command  to  test
>    attributes  of  files and to compare strings.  Field splitting and file
>    name generation are not performed on the words between [[ and ]].  Each
>    expression  can  be constructed from one or more of the following unary
>    or binary expressions:
>
>    **string** True, if string is not null.
>
>    ...
> ```

So the following expression is true:

```
[[ somestring ]]
```

Now consider your second example:

```
if [[ $SOME_VARIABLE="TRUE" ]]; then
```

Assuming `$SOME_VARIABLE` is "SOMETHINGNOTTRUE", this expands to:

```
if [[ SOMETHINGNOTTRUE=TRUE ]]; then
```

"SOMETHINGNOTTRUE=TRUE" is a non-zero length string. It is therefore true.

If you want to use operators inside of `[[`, you must put spaces around them as given in the docs (note the spaces):

```
   string == pattern
          True, if string matches pattern.  Any part  of  pattern  can  be
          quoted to cause it to be matched as a string.  With a successful
          match to a pattern, the .sh.match array  variable  will  contain
          the match and sub-pattern matches.
   string = pattern
          Same as == above, but is obsolete.
```

Comment: Thanks @Rob for the explanation.. I was expecting that we need to use operators along with escape characters if it needed to be taken as part of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Because the one argument form of the test is true if the string is not the empty string. Since the only argument ends in `=TRUE` it certainly isn't the empty string, so the test evaluates to true.

Space, the final frontier :-)

Always pay heed to your spaces and keep in mind the word splitting.

Comment: Hey thanks for the explanation @Jens! +1 for your comment "Space, the final frontier.." haha

Answer (score 0):

Just to pile on, this is explicitly called out in the ksh man page (in the description of the `test` command):

> Note that some special rules are applied (courtesy of POSIX) if the number of arguments to `test` or `[ ... ]` is less than five: if leading `!` arguments can be stripped such that **only one argument remains** then a **string length test is performed** (again, even if the argument is a unary operator)

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Just to add to this for newbies like myself...   Note:  A  common mistake is to use `if [ $foo = bar ]` which fails if parameter foo is null or unset, if  it  has  embedded  spaces (i.e.,  IFS  characters), or if it is a unary operator like `!` or `-n`.  Use tests like `if [ "X$foo" = Xbar ]` instead. Taken from [Reference ksh man page](http://ccrma.stanford.edu/planetccrma/man/man1/ksh.1.html)